# Is there a tool to update a project to a new version of Java?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm looking for something like an Eclipse plugin or wizard to step through a large code base (in Java 6) and point out the parts that need to be changed to update to Java 7, perhaps giving suggestions or tips.

I found instructions for doing it manually [here](http://vyazelenko.com/2012/02/01/is-your-project-ready-for-java-7/), but I was wondering if anyone knew of a tool to make the process more automated.

Comment: In this case, you're asking for a tool that can read the existing code, determine if there are issues, and rework the issues to utilized the new features.  That's not a tool, that's a developer.

Comment: @Rafflesiaarnoldii We both might privately agree, but please, be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish your goal by manipulating your build environment in Eclipse.

Just switch your JRE System Library being used for the project to Java 7 and see what breaks (Project > Java Build Path > Select and Edit `JRE System Library`) . Eclipse will give you fix suggestions if they are available for each issue. You can see a list of errors in the "Problems" view (Window > Show View > Problems).

Comment: I guess that's as automated as it gets.  Thanks.